# How can I point a function with function overload?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, overriding

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <functional>

int foo(int x)
{
    return x;
}

int foo(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

int main()
{
    std::function<int(int)> guiFunc2 = foo;      //error : no suitable constructor exists to convert from "<unknown-type>" to "std::function<int(int)>"
    std::function<int(int, int)> guiFunc1 = foo; //error : no suitable constructor exists to convert from "<unknown-type>" to "std::function<int(int, int)>"

    return 0;
}
```

I want to make two function pointers to functions with same name but this code does not work.

It's easy to just change the functions name but I would like to know if it's possible to make funtion pointers with same name.

Thanks.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overloaded_address

Comment: Hmm... why did @rafix07 remove the answer? It looked good, didn't it?

Comment: I fixed what I think was a typo, if it wasnt sorry.

Comment: Please, note the difference between function _overloading_ and _overriding_. Overriding is related to virtual functions and inheritance.

Comment: @DanielLangr Good catch. Edited since the code shows overloading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cast the address to correct type before assignment:

```
std::function<int(int)> guiFunc2 = static_cast<int(*)(int)>(foo);
std::function<int(int, int)> guiFunc1 = static_cast<int(*)(int, int)>(foo);
```

Comment: May I ask one more thing? What I've learnt is that 'c++ compiler discriminates one overrided function from another by check its 'arguments' and 'function name'' and the functions in my code have different arguments. Why must I type-cast them?

Comment: @GamerCoder You are not calling the function, so there are no arguments from which to deduct the type.

Comment: @GamerCoder `int(*guiFunc2)(int) = foo; int(*guiFunc1)(int,int) = foo;` works though if you don't like the casting.

Answer (score 0):

For me this is more handy:

```cpp
    auto a = [](int x) { return foo(x); };
    auto b = [](int a, int b) { return foo(a, b); };
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/yjc5EiEY97wgfN9b

Result should be same as other answer.